# Can someone please help me format this in String.Format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, hash

Can someone please help me convert this in a String format for C# code? I am not able to understand what this line of code does and my deployment is failing because of the $ sign.

```
   var verifyCode = $"{PREAMBLE} {apiKey}:{timeStamp}:{ Hash(apiKey, secretKey, timeStamp)}";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from *string interpolation* to `string.Format` you should move `{...}` from the string:

```
var verifyCode = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}:{3}", 
  PREAMBLE, 
  apiKey, 
  timeStamp, 
  Hash(apiKey, secretKey, timeStamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your c# version, it will update when you update visual studio. $ symbol was not supported in the old version of c#.

Comment: DevOps tried but said not working. So not sure.